# stdlib.h: No such file or directory when trying to build a simple Qt Android app

Tags: android, c++, qt, android-ndk, std

I want to develop an Android application using Qt 5.3 framework but I get the following error:

```
stdlib.h: No such file or directory
```

I'm under MacOS 10.9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using the 64 bit NDK and with the 32 bit NDK it works.

Comment: I change it. nothing happen and also I have this error .